# NSLog - Strange behavior

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nslog

I found that last word showed with double quotes. But why?

```
NSDictionary *guide2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:kArr, @"Kate", aArr, @"Ana-Lucia", kArr, @"John",  nil];
NSArray *array = [guide2 allKeys];
NSLog(@"%@", [array description]);
```

output:

```
(
John,
Kate,
"Ana-Lucia"
)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that because of the special character `-` in the key `Ana-Lucia`, it displays it within double-quotes. May be this is because **to show that the *key* is a single word**. If your key contains only `alphabets` like "AnaLucia", then it will display it without quotes.

The key is displayed in double-quotes if it contains any characters other than `alphabets`, even if it is an `underscore(_)` or `space`.

Answer (score 7):

Because it's not strictly alphanumeric and one word only. Try `NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"abc", @"123", @"$abc", @"a-b-c", @"a b c", nil];`, you'll see only the first two are not quoted. It's just an implementation choice from the guy who wrote the description code.