# NSStrings "containing_underscore_characters" are wrapped in quotation marks when set in NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsmutabledictionary

I'm adding NSStrings to an NSMutableDictionary. Some strings contain an underscore, some do not:

```
NSMutableDictionary *testDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[testDict setObject:@"_startWithUnderscore" forKey:@"firstKey"];
[testDict setObject:@"NoUnderscore" forKey:@"secondKey"];
[testDict setObject:@"underscores_in_middle" forKey:@"thirdKey"];
NSLog(@"%@", testDict);`
```

OUTPUT:

`firstKey = "_startWithUnderscore";` //Note the added quotation marks!

`secondKey = NoUnderscore;` //No quotation marks.

`thirdKey = "underscores_in_middle";` //Also gets quote marks.

Uh, what's going on here? Where are the quotation marks coming from?

Comment: Here you go. http://stackoverflow.com/q/7227163/491980

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ([[testDict objectForKey:@"firstKey"] substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)] isEqualToString:@"_"])
{
    NSLog(@"I guess the quotes are just things that NSLog prints, definitely not actually in the NSString.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its just a characteristic of NSLog.