# Parsing csv file to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, csv

I know the instructions are all over of how to read a .csv file in objective c then pass it to an NSMuatbleArray, but I'm getting problems when I assign it to a mutableArray. I've spent hours of checking online and trying to fix it, but nothing helped.

Here is my objective c code:

```
NSError *err;
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"/users/Mike/Desktop/Book1.csv" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err];

NSString *replace = [filePath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];
NSString *something = [replace stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"\n"];

NSMutableArray *columns = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[something componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"], nil];

NSLog(@"%@", filePath);
NSLog(@"%@", something);
NSLog(@"%@", columns);
```

Here is the output:

```
My App[1854:54976] Kitchen,Bathroom,Dinning Room,Living Room
My App[1854:54976] Kitchen
Bathroom
Dinning Room
Living Room

My App[1854:54976] (
        (
        Kitchen,
        Bathroom,
        "Dinning Room",
        "Living Room"
    )
)
```

The problem is that the output of the array comes with commas and quotations which I eliminated.
What I need is for the array "columns" to come out like the string "something".

**Update**

I took away the two strings of "replace" and "something" and switched the array to:

```
collumns = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[filePath componentsSeparatedByString:@","], nil];
```

Now I'm having trouble loading it to a table view. Here's my code for that.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"firstCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = [columns objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

The app just crashes with an unexplaned reason, but when I make another array manually, it works.
This one works:

```
NSMutableArrayrow = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"First", @"Second", nil];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSLog - Strange behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227163/nslog-strange-behavior)

Comment: It's different. The one you showed me, the problem was that it had special chars in it. ex. '-', that's why it put quotes there, here I don't have any special chars.

Comment: Yes you do -- whitespace characters.

Comment: In any case, that's irrelevant because the behavior you're seeing is simply how the array chooses to display its content (in this case by quoting certain strings). That quoting behavior doesn't cause the actual content to change.

Comment: I didn't realize that the quotes are not part of the text. thanks. But when I apply it to a uitextview, it shows the parenthesis. Is there away to get around that? textView.text = [columns componentsJoinedByString:@"\n "];

Comment: Update your question with how you put the array contents in the text view.

Comment: never mind, I got it. Sorry for the whole confusion. Not sure whats happening with me today

Comment: Can you please put a like by my question?

Comment: "put a like by my question"? What does that mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is a bit muddled, and contains one error that is the cause of your unexplained parenthesis.

- Why replace quotes with nothing when there are no quotes in the
  source data?
- Why replace commas with line breaks, and then split the string into
  an array of strings on the line breaks (which gets rid of the line
  breaks entirely)? Why not just split the string into an array using
  commas and skip the intermediate step?
- Finally, and most seriously, the method `initWithObjects` wants a
  comma-delimited set of objects, then a nil. You are passing it an
  array, and nil. So what you are getting as a result is a mutable
  array that contains a single object, an immutable array. This is
  almost certainly **not** what you want.

This line:

```
NSMutableArray *columns = 
  [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
    [something componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"], nil];
```

...is wrong.

You would use initWithObjects like this:

```
NSMutableArray *columns = 
  [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"one", @"two", @"three", nil];
```

Note how I'm passing in a comma-separated list of objects, and then a nil. Your use of initWithObjects is passing in a single object, an array, and then a nil. You won't get a mutable array that contains the objects from the source array - you'll get a mutable array that contains your starting immutable array.

It should be written like this instead:

```
NSMutableArray *columns = [[something componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"] 
  mutableCopy];
```

Or better yet, do it in 2 steps so it's clear whats going on:

```
NSArray *tempArray = [something componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
NSMutableArray *columns = [tempArray mutableCopy];
```

Comment: I get the first 2 points, I don't get the third one, and I don't get why you had to write the code. Also, the whole reason I want to export .csv to an array is because I want to load it to a UITableView, if you can help with that. Thanks

Comment: I tried your code and it works!! :) I just still don't understand I have to make a mutable copy

Comment: You don't need to make a mutable copy unless you need a mutable copy. I assumed that you had a logical reason to make your array into a mutable array. If you don't need the array to be mutable, skip the mutableCopy part, and just do this: `NSArray *columns = [something componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]`

Comment: Do you suggest me to use an array or mutable array?

Comment: To repeat: You don't need to make a mutable copy unless you need a mutable copy. If you don't need to change the array once you create it, make it an NSArray.